# Keep input field after submit and display response in the same page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css

I have a select div, with some options. When I select option 1, it shows me two buttons and for each button, when I click, it return me two tables (button one return me table one and button two return me table two). This is working ok, but I'm facing some problems to display the result after the php validate the inputed data.
What I have is this:

My php script:

```
<div id="main">
        <?php                                   
            $area = $_POST['area'];
           
            $url = "http://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/$area";  
            
            $ch = curl_init($url);

            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

            $result = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);
            
            $data = json_decode($result, true);       
        ?>    

    <div class="select">
        <select onchange="displayDiv('hide-buttons', this)">
            <option value="0">Select an action</option> 
            <option value="1">Create</option> 
            <option value="2">Consult</option>   
        </select>
    </div> 

    <div id="hide-buttons" style="display:none">
        <div class="col-md-8">
                <button id="button1" onclick="showTable1()">Time</button>
                <button id="button2" onclick="showTable2()">Area</button>  
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="table1" style="display:none"> 
            <form method="POST">
                <label for="area">Insert area:</label>
                <input type="text" id="area" name="area"> 
                <input class="button3" type="submit"> 
            </form>
            
            <?php 
            if (empty($area)) {
                    echo "<p class='empty-message'>" . "Insert an area" . "</p>";       
                ?>
                    <tr></tr>
                    <td></td>
                        
                <?php } else if (preg_match('/error/',$result)){ 
                    echo "<p class='invalid-message'>" . "Invalid area" . "</p>";
                ?>
                    <tr></tr>
                    <td></td>
                    
                <?php } else { 
                    echo "<p class='valid-message'>" . "Valid area" . "</p>";                   
                ?>   
        
            <table id="area-value">
                <tr>
                    <th>Area</th>
                </tr>
                    
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $data["timezone"];}?></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>   

        <div id="table2" style="display:none"> 
            <form method="POST">
                <label for="area">Insert time:</label>
                <input type="text" id="area" name="area"> 
                <input class="button3" type="submit"> 
            </form>

            <?php 
            if (empty($area)) {
                    echo "<p class='empty-message'>" . "Insert an area" . "</p>";       
                ?>
                    <tr></tr>
                    <td></td>
                        
                <?php } else if (preg_match('/error/',$result)){ 
                    echo "<p class='invalid-message'>" . "Invalid area" . "</p>";
                ?>
                    <tr></tr>
                    <td></td>
                    
                <?php } else { 
                    echo "<p class='valid-message'>" . "Valid area" . "</p>";                   
                ?>   

            <table id="time-value">
                <tr>
                    <th>Time</th>
                </tr>
                    
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $data["datetime"];}?></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>

</div>
```

And JavaScript:

```
    function displayDiv(id, elementValue) {
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = elementValue.value == 2 ? 'block' : 'none';
  }
  
  function showTable1() {
    document.getElementById("table2").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("table1").style.display = "none";
  }
  
  function showTable2() {
    document.getElementById("table2").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("table1").style.display = "block";
  }
```

As you can test, my problem is when I submit the input, it will make the request and retrieve the response, but I have to select option and click on the button again to see the response. I'm very new to it, I tried to made changes but it keeps getting worst. How can I do it?

Comment: Is this a JS problem, a PHP problem, or a CSS problem? What have you tried to resolve it? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

You could make a function on load to check the response div and see if it has changes, and then you can directly show the div with the results, or trigger the button click, how to do that?

I first assume you have jQuery installed because then it's easier to just create an event rather than doing it in plain javascript (it's also helpful to use jQuery if you are starting), so if you have jQuery you could do this:

```
function displayDiv(id, elementValue) {
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = elementValue.value == 2 ? 'block' : 'none';
}

function showTable1() {
    document.getElementById("table2").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("table1").style.display = "none";
}

function showTable2() {
    document.getElementById("table2").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("table1").style.display = "block";
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    checkForResponse(); // calls this function when loading the screen
});


function checkForResponse(){
    //Checks if table1 child p element has valid-message then shows the table1
    if($('#table1 p').hasClass('valid-message')){
        showTable1();
    }

    //Checks if table2 child p element has valid-message then shows the table2
    if($('#table2 p').hasClass('valid-message')){
        showTable2();
    }
}
```

This could be later refactored but I think is an idea to get you going, good luck.